# Merge disjoint object arrays in JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-manipulation

I'm struggling to find an elegant and reliable way of merging two arrays in vanilla JS or d3.js, where

- the "rows" of the series do not necessarily match;
- objects may share some but not all attributes;
- "missing" attributes are filled in as null.

For example, two arrays of the form

```
A = 
[
    {
        year : 2001, 
        gdp : 1.1, 
        population : 1100
    },
    {
        year : 2002, 
        gdp : 1.2, 
        population : 1200
    },
]

B = 
[
    {
        year : 2000, 
        gdp : 1.0, 
        rainfall : 100
    },
    {
        year : 2001, 
        gdp : 1.1, 
        rainfall : 110
    }
]
```

would ideally combine to give

```
C = 
[
    {
        year : 2000, 
        gdp : 1.0, 
        population : null,
        rainfall : 10
    },
    {
        year : 2001, 
        gdp : 1.1, 
        population : 1100,
        rainfall : 110
    },
    {
        year : 2002, 
        gdp : 1.2, 
        population : 1200,
        rainfall : null
    },
]
```

I can usually figure this kind of thing out but this one has got me really stuck!

Comment: is `gdp` a fixed value or dynamic? what have you tried?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, gdp is fixed in that it will be identical for each year. I was trying to use d3.nest but I'm not seeing how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build an array of all items, get the keys and build an empty object as pattern for an empty object. Then group by `year` and get the values. Apply sorting if necessary.

```js
const
    a = [{ year: 2001, gdp: 1.1, population: 1100 }, { year: 2002, gdp: 1.2, population: 1200 }],
    b = [{ year: 2000, gdp: 1.0, rainfall: 100 }, { year: 2001, gdp: 1.1, rainfall: 110 }],
    items = [...a, ...b],
    empty = Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(Object.assign({}, ...items)).map(k => [k, null])),
    result = Object
        .values(items.reduce((r, o) => {
            r[o.year] ??= { ...empty };
            Object.assign(r[o.year], o);
            return r;
        }, {}))
        .sort((a, b) => a.year - b.year);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```